What exactly are Django Widgets?
I am a little confused as to what exactly Django Widgets are. From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/forms/widgets/:

The widget handles the rendering of the HTML, and the extraction of data from a GET/POST dictionary that corresponds to the widget."


What exactly is meant by extraction of data from GET/POST dict? That is done by the passing data argument to form instantiation, how does Widget come into picture here?

If I understood correctly, Widgets just create the HTML <input> tags, and take attr parameters that set attributes of this input tag, viz. size (in case of text input), required (override on the field required value), class, etc. So how exactly do packages like crispy-forms+crispy-bootstrap5, django-bootstrap5 differ from these Widgets? And what do they do with Django Widgets? Also, these packages have parameters when rendering a field where css_class (the actual class of the input) can be modified. How does this play with Widget attr['class']?

Does Django have templates for each Widget in files (like rest of the templates in the Django template system)?



Widgets provide the actual UI with which form fields take their values. Yes, that's typically just an <input> tag, but it can be anything you want. You can render highly complex multi-element HTML structures with a widget, which in the end just provides one value for one form field. It's also the job of the widget to turn that complex data back into one field value.

I've found the simplest way to understand widgets is exploring the Django source code for a widget that's close(ish) to what I want. Then inherit and override and play. They are  low-level stuff. Start here https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/widgets.py

Yes, I am doing that currently for both Django widgets, and the fore-mentioned packages. If I had a higher level view, I thought it'd be easier to understand the code I am reading.


What exactly is meant by extraction of data from GET/POST dict? That is done by the passing data argument to form instantiation, how does Widget come into picture here?

Indeed, you pass the data to a form. But a form is, essentially, just a group of form fields (ok, this is a bit an oversimplification). The form itself does not have logic to extract the date from a DateTimeField form field [Django-doc].
Essentially what happens is that the form enumerates over all form fields with the data it received, so every form field can try to find the data and process it accordingly.
A form field does not know how to extract data from the HTML either. A form field works with a widget, or multiple widgets. Widgets serve two purposes: rendering HTML for a HTML form, and extracting the data from these HTML elements in simple values.
A form field then can combine the values defined in the widget into a Python object that the form field is supposed to generate, and also do some validation.
Then finally a form is given a dictionary of these values, to do further cleaning and validation on the collection of all the values in the form.

So how exactly do packages like crispy-forms+crispy-bootstrap5, django-bootstrap5 differ from these Widgets?

These tools change how the rendering process works. For example by adding extra attributes to the widgets already defined, or change how to render the entire form together: a form is rendered in Django by enumerating over the form fields, the form fields are then rendered (by the logic provided by the widgets of these form fields), and combined. One can provide a different template, or work with more sophisticated logic to combine the HTML generated by the widgets.

Does Django have templates for each Widget in files (like rest of the templates in the Django template system)?

Yes, although the template are often not very fancy. This is the template [GitHub] for example is one for the TextInput [Django-doc] widget. You can override a template to thus change how an already existing widget is rendered.
